# When I enter the app for the second time the two buttons are still pressed

Tags: ios, if-statement, uibutton

There are two buttons (say `Btn1` and `Btn2`) in my app when I press the `Btn1`, `Btn2` is enabled for user interaction and to perform an action. There is no problem in that.

Now the problem is,

I want the button to get back to the default state as it was at the start (when I press the ``` Btn1``Btn2 ``` is enabled for user interaction and to perform an action)

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)Btn1:(id)sender;    
{
    // if the Btn1 pressed enable the Btn2
    if (...)
    {
        button.enabled = YES;   
    }
}

- (IBAction)Btn2:(id)sender;
{
    if (button.enabled == YES) 
        // do any action in here    
    } 
}
```

Comment: First of all, a button has to be enabled to be able to pressed. If you want to initiate the `Btn2:(id)sender` action then use `performSelector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the default state in function viewWillAppear.

Something like this:

.h header file

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *button1; // connect to the button in interface builder
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *button2; // connect to the button in interface builder

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)button; // set this as an action for both buttons
```

.m file

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated]
    [self defaultState];
}

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)button;   
{
    if (button == self.button1) { // button 1 pressed        
       self.button2.enabled = YES;   
    } else if (button == self.button2) { // button 2 was pressed
       [self defaultState]; // go back to default state
    }
}

-(void)defaultState {  // your default state of the app
   self.button2.enabled = NO;
   // other stuff
}
```

Comment: i have an idea what if i make the whole view start from the begin after the **Btn2** open and pressed. cause i dont want just the button to be un enabled i want the action inside the button 2. there is any code you can help me with to make the view start from the begin after **Btn2** pressed?

Comment: Can you explain me what are you trying to do ?

Comment: im trying to rest the button state like the begin when i start the app

Answer (score 0):

You could add a convenience method `resetButtonStates` to your view controller, and have it called in two ways:

1. In `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`
2. Whenever `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` is posted by your app. This is because `viewWillAppear:` is not called when you bring your app to the foreground. Register for this notification using NSNotifcationCenter (see the docs for more info).

In `resetButtonStates` you should update the buttons to the appropriate state (enabled/disabled/etc.).